# Collection.insert is not a function - Meteor

Tags: meteor, collections, mongoose

Good day developers! I'm working with Meteor.js it's my 1st expirience
I created collection in file

```
 // ./dbs/messages.js

import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check'; 

export const Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');
```

and use it in api point with calling   `Messages.insert` like that

```
// server/mail.js

import Messages from './dbs/messages.js';

Meteor.methods({
 'message.post'(messageText, location){
    Messages.insert({
      messageText: messageText,
      location: location
    });
  }
})
```

But when I call `'message.post'` I get an error

```
Exception while invoking method 'message.post' TypeError
Messages.insert is not a function
```

BUT, when I comment collection import and declare it in `server/main.js` like that

```
// import Messages from './dbs/messages.js';
const Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');

Meteor.methods({
 'message.post'(messageText, location){
    Messages.insert({
      messageText: messageText,
      location: location
    });
  }
});
```

In this case my `Messages.insert` works properly.

**Who has experience with Meteor - can you explain me what is the reason?**
Thanks!
Also I have removed `autopublish` and `insecure` packages

Comment: Most likely an import issue. You should import it as a named import (`import {Messages} from...`), or export it as default.

Comment: use curly braces like `import { Messages } from './dbs/messages.js';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @MasterAM and @Ankur Soni said you need to import Messages using brackets `import { Messages } from './dbs/messages.js';`
The only way to import without brackets is by defining Messages and then exporting it like so `export default Messages;`

Answer (score 0):

I initiate my collections in a "common" space. I feel what you did is actually right. You either declare the collection twice, once on the client side and once on the server side or do it only once in a common folder. I see in many documentations that the popular place to keep these declarations is the /imports/api ... which is common to both server and client.

Rgs,
Paul